# Are there simple examples of two distinct transitive sets that are elementary embeddable in each other?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

This question had be edited altogether in a more concise manner.

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are transitive sets such that there exist elementary embeddings $f:(M,\in)\to(N,\in)$ and $g:(N,\in)\to (M,\in)$. Does it follow that $M=N$?

If not, then can this be shown by a rather simple example?

Note: The revised question had been posted at [MathOverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437699/can-we-have-mutual-elementary-embeddability-between-distinct-transitive-sets/)

Comment: No! The language is different.

Comment: Really? Why not translate every sentence in "the language of ZFC" into a sentence in the language of ordered sets by replacing every $\in$ by $<$?

Comment: @AnneBauval, its not very clear to me. I call for a simpler answer.

Comment: There is no difference between $<$ and $\in$ when looking at an ordinal - they're exactly the same thing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, still that posting about those ordinals was not easy to comprehend. Arn't their clearer examples?

Comment: If the only way this question differs from that one is that you're looking for simpler examples, you should make that much clearer in the **body** (and title ideally) of the question. As this post stands, it's just asking a yes/no question which is indeed easily answered by the linked post, with the only hint towards an easier answer being the afterthought-seeming last line.

Comment: As far as examples go, an old theorem in Rosenstein's book *Linear orderings* shows e.g. that $\omega^\omega$ and $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$ are elementarily equivalent as transitive sets; see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3422333/28111). So if you don't add any additional complexity requirements on your transitive sets, there are very simple examples indeed. If, on the other hand, you want your transitive sets to satisfy (say) $\mathsf{KP}$, then there aren't going to be any too-easy examples.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, hmmm... Ok, then.

Comment: The new version of your question is really quite a different matter! Note that the existence of an elementary embedding $M\to N$ implies $\mathrm{Th}(M) = \mathrm{Th}(N)$. So your question could be more concisely stated as follows: "Suppose $M$ and $N$ are transitive sets such that there exist elementary embeddings $f\colon (M,\in)\to (N,\in)$ and $g\colon (N,\in)\to (M,\in)$. Does it follow that $M = N$?"

Comment: @AlexKruckman, I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that the property holds. (note that we can replace "transitive sets" with "well founded relationship" and "$=$" with "$≅$" by Mostowski collapse), one can show that "elementarily bi-embeddable implies isomorphism" for a complete theory $T$ of countable language implies $T$ is superstable (and more), and while you are asking for a weaker property than the SB-property, I feel like requiring well-foundness is not strong enough

Comment: @ℋolo Requiring well-foundedness changes everything. Consider the theory of linear orders: no two non-isomorphic well-founded linear orders are bi-embeddable, let alone bi-elementarily-embeddable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber of course it changes stuff, but the SB-property implies some very strong well behavior properties on the theory, and well-founded sets can be very complicated (I would imagine that sufficiently complicated trees would almost always be elementary bi-embeddable). Being well founded does trivialize the linear case and remove theories that are (in some sense) "internally ugly", but the big class that is left is very rich

Comment: @ℋolo A *first-order* theory with the SB-property must be very tame, but the theory of well-founded relations is not first-order (nor even axiomatizable in $L_{\infty,\omega}$!). A lot of nice theorems in first-order model theory go right out the window when we try to generalize to other logics. I don't have a clear intuition about which way this question should go.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is trivial indeed : there are at most $2^\omega$ possible theories in the language $L := \{ \in \}$, and there are WAY more transitive sets. Hence, there are distinct transitive sets that have the same theory.

Comment: I asked for an example of such models.

Comment: You haven't answered the duplicated question.

Comment: I've done that. I answered by No and submitted it.

Comment: I wanted a simpler answer, an clear example of two such models which can be easily understood.

Comment: @Can a version of this answer, answer the revised question? So the question here is: even if we have way more transitive sets than theories, and accordingly having many transitive sets capturing the same theory, still why we need those to be bi-embeddable?

Comment: @Zuhair No - for example, **no** pair of distinct ordinals are mutually embeddable (let alone mutually elementarily embeddable). So a simple counting argument won't work here. Basically, the existence of an elementary embedding is **vastly** stronger (and just different in nature) than mere elementary equivalence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, is it known to be consistent [or inconsistent] with ZF to have two distinct transitive sets that are mutually elementarily embeddable? If it is inconsistent then I'm right about the implication in the question, if it is known consistent, then what are the examples? And at what consistency level we begin to have that? That's really the question.